# ¿Cómo validar un monto ($) en el modelo antes de ser guadado en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Requiero validar que `monto_ingresado` no exceda `total_a_pagar`, pero empieza a hacer la validación después de creado y requiero que sea validado desde la primera vez:

```
validate :validar_monto

def validar_monto
  if monto_ingresado > total_a_pagar
errors.add(:monto_ingresado, "El monto ingresado es mayor, su deuda es   de #{total_a_pagar}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Solo por estar seguro, pero ¿estás seguro de que efectivamente no está llamando al método `validar_monto`? ¿has verificado los valores de `monto_ingresado` y `total_a_pagar` cuando llama al método?

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar un poco más sobre el objeto que quieres guardar? Toda validación en rails se hace **antes** de guardar el objeto, y el código que muestras no tiene falla (por lo que debería fucionar). ¿O a qué te refieres con *validado desde la primera vez*?

Comment: Me refiero a la primera vez cuando ejemplo supongamos que tengo que hacer un pago a un cliente el monto_a_pagar es 10 cierto y en campo monto_ingresado colocó 11, me permite guardarlo. Lo que requiero es que cuando ocurra eso no lo permita.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código completo del modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es muy claro para mi lo que requieres.

Creo que lo que necesitas es "validar" antes de guardar en el modelo, utiliza `before_save`, puedes leer mas aqui: [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Entonces, no uses:

```
validate :validar_monto
```

En vez de eso, usa:

```
before_save :validar_monto
```